# Reference for solved exercises in additive combinatorics

Tags: reference-request, additive-combinatorics

I am aware that additive combinatorics is a relatively new subject and there are not many books available.

I will be grateful if anybody can tell me about some source where I can find a few solved exercises in this subject.

I have not found any book or course notes.
Thanks!

Comment: What about the book of Tao and Vu?

Comment: The book is very nice but it does not have any solved exercises or examples!

Comment: Adam Sheffer has some notes on additive combinatorics on his blog. I don't remember if he has exercises, but it's probably more accessible than Tao and Vu.

Comment: How about Lovasz book on Solved problems in Combinatorics

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3319010/references-for-combinatorics-of-finite-sets

Comment: @asahay Sheffer's notes are certainly useful. They have more computational stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Lovasz book is the best resource for the problems I could find so far. Thank you so much @vidyarthi